# Controlling for baseline differences?

Tags: meta-analysis

I am comparing two groups, with data before and after retirement, to see the effect retirement has on depression levels.

The control group works over the two measurement points, and the retirees group works at baseline and retires at post.

Let's say I have the mean, SD and sample size of each of these groups pre/post retirement, how do I calculate the effect size for the change in depression levels for the retirees group, that controls for the differences in depression level between the groups at baseline?

Answer (score -1):

Unless you randomly assigned some people to be randomized and other to continued work, you have much worse issues to deal with than just baseline differences. Even if it were a randomized experiment, you would ideally want the individual records (although perhaps the covariance between baseline and post-baseline might be nearly as good under the assumption of a linear effect of the baseline value on the later value) so that you can fit a regression model.

As it is there are a number of possible methods (e.g. propensity scores or regression adjustment) to do this in a sensible way, if you have access to the individual records and you have collected information on *all* the things that might influence both the decision to retire and the outcome.

Comment: While your first sentence is true, it is unfriendly and does not directly address the OP's question.